# Returning mutable reference to trait in "get_trait_mut"

Tags: rust

Consider the following:

```
pub trait Inner {}

pub struct Thing<'a> {
    inner: &'a Inner,
}

impl<'a> Thing<'a> {
    pub fn get_inner(&self) -> &Inner {
        self.inner
    }

    pub fn get_inner_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Inner {
        &mut self.inner
    }
}
```

leads to:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&'a (dyn Inner + 'a): Inner` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:13:9
   |
13 |         &mut self.inner
   |         -^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         the trait `Inner` is not implemented for `&'a (dyn Inner + 'a)`
   |         help: consider removing 1 leading `&`-references
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Inner`
```

Which is fair, so let's follow the advice, shall we?

Same as above with this change:

```
pub fn get_inner_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Inner {
    mut self.inner
}
```

```
error: expected expression, found keyword `mut`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:9
   |
13 |         mut self.inner
   |         ^^^ expected expression
```

(found keyword mut is what my local compiler says, not the one in the playground link below though!)

Hm, makes sense, right? `mut` alone is not an expression

But how to return a mutable reference then?

Okay, let's get experimenting a bit, shall we?

```
pub fn get_inner_mut(&mut self) -> &mut &Inner {
    &mut &self.inner
}
```

(Attention, changed signature!)

leads to:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:13:9
   |
13 |         &mut &self.inner
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected type `&mut &dyn Inner`
              found type `&mut &'a (dyn Inner + 'a)`
note: the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 12:5...
  --> src/lib.rs:12:5
   |
12 | /     pub fn get_inner_mut(&mut self) -> &mut &Inner {
13 | |         &mut &self.inner
14 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 7:6
  --> src/lib.rs:7:6
   |
7  | impl<'a> Thing<'a> {
   |      ^^
```

Could this all be solved with just specifying the lifetime?

Here is [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef5cc6cd6011c690ae291347ef570446)

Comment: Why do you believe that a `&mut &Inner` is a `&mut Inner`? Those ampersands aren't just for show.

Comment: @Shepmaster Basically I wanted to get a better error message than `help: consider removing 1 leading `&`-references`, but that clearly backfired on me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see is that `Thing` only has an **immutable** reference to `inner`.

Here is my take on this:

```
pub trait Inner {}

pub struct Thing<'a> {
    inner: &'a mut Inner,
}

impl<'a> Thing<'a> {
    pub fn get_inner(&self) -> &Inner {
        self.inner
    }

    pub fn get_inner_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Inner {
        &mut *self.inner
    }
}

struct SomeInner {}

impl Inner for SomeInner {}

fn main() {
    let mut inner = SomeInner {};
    let mut thing = Thing { inner: &mut inner };

    let inner: &Inner = thing.get_inner();
    let mutable_inner: &mut Inner = thing.get_inner_mut();
}
```

It compiles (as you can verify [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e775e188378674fd1a0638711912598f))

**note**:

- `let mut inner = SomeInner {}` -> `inner` is mutable
- `let mut thing` -> `thing` is also mutable
- `&mut *self.shape` -> I am dereferencing the reference and then creating a mutable reference to it again

I am sure there are more sophisticated solutions and I hope that someone else will contribute such.

**edit**: as Shepmaster kindly pointed out, there is no need at all to write `&mut *self.shape`. As we already have access to a mutable reference, just returning `self.inner` is enough - the compiler will make sure that the mutability is honored.

In the end, my attempt would become:

```
impl<'a> Thing<'a> {
   pub fn get_inner(&self) -> &Inner {
     self.inner
   }

   pub fn get_inner_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Inner {
      self.inner
   }
}
```

[Full example on playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=55d495742fa449d0b0531d906cbe01a3)

Comment: *`&mut *self.inner`* — **Why**, though? Just `self.inner` would be fine.

Comment: @Shepmaster Of course you're right: What the hell came over me? Thanks for pointing this out!